# How to use Okta with Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, okta, openid-connect

I am using Keycloak with my Spring Boot application. I want to use Okta as Identity Provider without success, this configuration:

Spring configuration:

```
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://dev-XXXXXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
security.oauth2.resource.tokenInfoUri=https://dev-XXXXXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=false

security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://dev-XXXXXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://dev-XXXXXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
security.oauth2.client.clientId=CLIENT_ID
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid profile email
```

Okta Identity Provider configuration:
[image]

But this configuration is always leading me to HTTP 400:

[image]

What I am missing?

Comment: I've never used Keycloak to talk to Okta before. Why don't you just configure your app to talk to Okta directly?

Comment: I have security constrains forcing me to use okta only for authentication. So for the authorization, I can use keycloak or the classic jdbc solution.

Comment: Why do you need Keycloak if you have Okta? They do the same thing.

Comment: @NebrassLamouchi did you successfully do this integration? Any article for the same would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure your Spring Boot to work with Keycloak and then Keycloak to work with Okta.

The following article describes how to configure Keycloak with Okta SAML Provider

https://ultimatesecurity.pro/post/okta-saml/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer it with surety, but have you added redirect-url to the trusted origins of Okta dashboard?

https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget?_ga=2.16453941.2053718723.1521541302-1766190875.1521541302

Comment: The url is correctly trusted, but I still have this error :(